# Como não retornar somente a última frase no for loop?

Tags: python

Estou criando um `for` para armazenar os dados de cada evento em uma frase para depois uni-las em uma string. Porém só obtenho retorno do último valor.

```
qtd_eventos = int(input('Informe a quantidade de eventos: '))

eventos_advesos = []
previsibilidades = []
descricoes = []

for i in range(qtd_eventos):
  print('-----------------------NOVO EVENTO--------------------------')
  eventos_advesos.append(input('Informe o evento adverso: '))
  print('------------------------------------------------------------')
  previsibilidades.append(input('Informe a previsibilidade em bula: '))
  print('------------------------------------------------------------') 
  descricoes.append(input('Informe se o evento é descrito em bula: '))
  print('------------------------------------------------------------')

analise_eventos = list([f'{i} é ' for i in eventos_advesos])
analise_previsao = list([f'classificado como {e} ' for e in previsibilidades])
analise_descricao = list([f'e {a} segundo a bula.' for a in descricoes])

for i in analise_eventos:
  evento = i
for e in analise_previsao:
  evento = i + e 
for a in analise_descricao:
  evento = i + e + a

print(evento)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso aqui:

```
analise_eventos = list([f'{i} é ' for i in eventos_advesos])
analise_previsao = list([f'classificado como {e} ' for e in previsibilidades])
analise_descricao = list([f'e {a} segundo a bula.' for a in descricoes])
```

Não parece fazer muito sentido. Não vejo motivo para criar 3 listas adicionais com os textos, para depois tentar juntá-los.

Mesmo que fizesse sentido, depois você faz isso:

```
for i in analise_eventos:
    evento = i
```

Ou seja, a cada iteração do *loop*, você **sobrescreve** o valor de `evento`. Por isso que no final essa variável só vai ter o último valor.

---

Se a ideia é somente imprimir, não precisa desse trabalho todo. Você pode percorrer as listas simultaneamente com [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), e aí basta imprimir os dados no formato desejado:

```
for evento, prev, desc in zip(eventos_advesos, previsibilidades, descricoes):
    print(f'{evento} é classificado como {prev} e {desc} segundo a bula')
```

A cada iteração do `for`, as variáveis `evento`, `prev` e `desc` serão um dos elementos das listas `eventos_advesos`, `previsibilidades` e `descricoes`.

Mas se você quer muito criar uma variável contendo todo o texto, para todos os elementos, pode usar [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) juntamente com uma [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
texto = '\n'.join( # separa os textos por "\n" (quebra de linha)
    f'{evento} é classificado como {prev} e {desc} segundo a bula'
    for evento, prev, desc in zip(eventos_advesos, previsibilidades, descricoes)
)
print(texto)
```

No caso, eu usei `\n` (quebra de linha), assim os textos ficarão um em cada linha. Mas você pode usar o caractere que quiser - por exemplo, se fizer `', '.join(etc...)`, os textos serão separados por vírgula e espaço.

---

#### Alternativa para as 3 listas

Mas se a ideia é guardar informações relacionadas (pois entendi que cada evento tem a sua respectiva previsibilidade e descrição), uma opção melhor do que ter 3 listas é ter uma única lista, e agrupar as informações em uma [tupla](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-tuple):

```
dados = []
for i in range(qtd_eventos):
  evento = input('Informe o evento adverso: ')
  previsibilidade = input('Informe a previsibilidade em bula: ')
  descricao = input('Informe se o evento é descrito em bula: ')
  dados.append((evento, previsibilidade, descricao)) # insere uma tupla com as 3 informações
```

Repare nos parênteses adicionais, eles são importantes. Se eu fizer apenas:

```
dados.append(evento, previsibilidade, descricao)
```

Isso dá erro porque estou passando 3 parâmetros para `append`. Mas ao colocar os parênteses adicionais, estou criando uma tupla contendo os 3 valores (`evento`, `previsibilidade` e `descricao`) e inserindo esta tupla na lista `dados`.

Depois, basta percorrer esta lista e obter os valores de cada tupla:

```
for evento, prev, desc in dados:
    print(f'{evento} é classificado como {prev} e {desc} segundo a bula')

# ou
texto = '\n'.join(
    f'{evento} é classificado como {prev} e {desc} segundo a bula'
    for evento, prev, desc in dados
)
print(texto)
```